# why is form.is_valid returns false?with this error?

Tags: python, django

what is this error????

```html
<ul class="errorlist"><li>username<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li><li>password<ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul></li></ul>
```

html file

```html
<form name="form" action="/accounts/logincheck" method="POST" >
          {% csrf_token %}
          <div class="container">

              <div class="login">
                <h1>Login to your account</h1>

                    <input type="text" name="u" placeholder="Username" required="required"/>
                    <input type="password" name="p" placeholder="Password" required="required"/>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Login</button>

              </div>
          </div>
      </form>
```

View.py file

```html
def logincheck(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        MyLoginForm = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if MyLoginForm.is_valid():
            username = MyLoginForm.cleaned_data['u']
            password = MyLoginForm.cleaned_data['p']
            print("Username : "+username)
            print("Password : "+password)
            response = redirect("/login")
        else:
            print(MyLoginForm.errors)
            response = redirect("/logout")
    else:
        response = redirect("/profile")

    return response
```

forms.py

```html
from django import forms

class LoginForm(forms.Form):
   username = forms.CharField(max_length=100)
   password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput())
```

i dont know why form.is_valid returning false and even the error is not interpreted to me!!
what it is actually telling!

Thanks in advance

Comment: You will have to add your related code and suitable sample data.

Comment: Impossible to say without seeing your code ...

Comment: Its pretty clear, the username is a required field

Comment: hi, @Klaus D.
now, could you please identify the issue!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi @urbanespaceman
now, could you please identify the issue!!

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi  @Sayse
now, could you please identify the issue!!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view is incorrect.
You need to authenticate user first then after if the user credentials are right then you can redirect to some url like this.

Change your view like this.

```
def logincheck(request):
     if request.method == "POST":
        MyLoginForm = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if MyLoginForm.is_valid():
            username = MyLoginForm.cleaned_data['u']
            password = MyLoginForm.cleaned_data['p']
            print("Username : ",username)
            print("Password : ",password)
            user = authenticate(request,username=u,password=p)
            if user is not None:
                return redirect("some-path")
     else:
             MyLoginForm = LoginForm()
     return render(reuqest,'your_login_template',{'form': MyLoginForm})
```

Comment: right now, i just want to print the values of username/password in console, when the login button is pressed in html file

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `u` and `p` in name of the input fields, you should use `username` and `password`.

```
<input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username" required="required"/>
<input type="password" name="password" id="username" placeholder="Password" required="required"/>
```

Also, update the view to get data from `username` and `password`:

```
def logincheck(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_login_form = LoginForm(request.POST)

        if my_login_form.is_valid():
            username = my_login_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = my_login_form.cleaned_data['password']
            # authentication should be done here. documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/
            return redirect('/profile')
```

Finally, as you are working with django forms, why not use it in template?

To do that, you need to send the form data to template, like this:

```
def logincheck(request):
    my_login_form = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    if request.method == "POST":
        if my_login_form.is_valid():
            username = my_login_form.cleaned_data['username']
            password = my_login_form.cleaned_data['password']
            # authentication should be done here. documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/
            return redirect('/profile')
     return render('logincheck_template.html', context={'form':my_login_form})
```

And use it template:

```
<div class="login">
    <h1>Login to your account</h1>
       {% for field in form %}
           {{ field.errors }}
           {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
       {% endfor %}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-large">Login</button>
 </div>
```